# Rails json request is taking most of its time in rendering views. How to make it faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, view

Currently, a request is taking a long time. The log I get is

```
Completed 200 OK in 22365ms (Views: 17995.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1280.4ms)
```

This is an iOS rails application and actually no view is being generated. Is there a way to reduce the time taken to render views in iOS rails application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of ways to reduce the request time :

```
1) Minimize HTTP Requests
2) Use a Content Delivery Network
3) Avoid empty src or href
4) Add an Expires or a Cache-Control Header
5) Gzip Components
6) Put StyleSheets at the Top
7) Put Scripts at the Bottom
8) Avoid CSS Expressions
9) Make JavaScript and CSS External
10) Reduce DNS Lookups
11) Minify JavaScript and CSS
12) Avoid Redirects
13) Remove Duplicate Scripts
14) Configure ETags
15) Make AJAX Cacheable
16) Use GET for AJAX Requests
17) Reduce the Number of DOM Elements
18) No 404s
19) Reduce Cookie Size
20) Do Not Scale Images in HTML
21) Make favicon.ico Small and Cacheable
```

you can read all this in more detail http://yslow.org/

Comment: Thank you for various suggestions!